# Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8080 inside dockerized vue application

Tags: docker, vue.js, cypress

I have a vuejs application that I am attempting to setup headless tests for using docker + docker-compose. I can't seem to get around an issue where the services both appear to start correctly, but can't seem to communicated with one another:

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:lts-alpine

WORKDIR /app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install -f

EXPOSE 8080
# Note 8080 is exposed! I'm not crazy!
CMD ["npm", "run", "serve"]
```

docker-compose file:

```
version: '3.5'
services:
    my-app:
        build: .
        ports: 
            - "8080:8080"
        volumes:
          - type: bind
            source: ./app
            target: /app
          - "/app/node_modules"
    cypress:
      image: "cypress/included:8.2.0"
      depends_on:
        - my-app
      #environment:
      #  - CYPRESS_baseUrl=http://localhost:8080
      working_dir: /app
      volumes: 
        - type: bind
          source: ./app
          target: /app

volumes: 
  app:
```

However, cypress spits out errors like:

```
cypress_1  | http://localhost:8080/thank-you
cypress_1  | 
cypress_1  | We attempted to make an http request to this URL but the request failed without a response.
cypress_1  | 
cypress_1  | We received this error at the network level:
cypress_1  | 
cypress_1  |   > Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8080
cypress_1  | 
cypress_1  | Common situations why this would fail:
cypress_1  |   - you don't have internet access
cypress_1  |   - you forgot to run / boot your web server
cypress_1  |   - your web server isn't accessible
cypress_1  |   - you have weird network configuration settings on your computer
cypress_1  |       at http://localhost:44829/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:143973:23
cypress_1  |       at visitFailedByErr (http://localhost:44829/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:143332:12)
cypress_1  |       at http://localhost:44829/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:143972:11
cypress_1  |       at tryCatcher (http://localhost:44829/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:13212:23)
cypress_1  |       at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (http://localhost:44829/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:11147:31)
cypress_1  |       at Promise._settlePromise (http://localhost:44829/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:11204:18)
cypress_1  |       at Promise._settlePromise0 (http://localhost:44829/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:11249:10)
cypress_1  |       at Promise._settlePromises (http://localhost:44829/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:11325:18)
cypress_1  |       at _drainQueueStep (http://localhost:44829/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:7919:12)
cypress_1  |       at _drainQueue (http://localhost:44829/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:7912:9)
cypress_1  |       at Async.../../node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js.Async._drainQueues (http://localhost:44829/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:7928:5)
cypress_1  |       at Async.drainQueues (http://localhost:44829/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:7798:14)
cypress_1  |   From Your Spec Code:
cypress_1  |       at Context.eval (http://localhost:44829/__cypress/tests?p=tests/e2e/specs/views/ThankYou.js:101:8)
cypress_1  |   
cypress_1  |   From Node.js Internals:
cypress_1  |     Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8080
cypress_1  |         at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1146:16)
```

References that I used to come up with this setup:

- https://www.cypress.io/blog/2019/05/02/run-cypress-with-a-single-docker-command/
- https://github.com/bahmutov/cypress-open-from-docker-compose/blob/master/e2e/docker-compose.yml
- https://github.com/bahmutov/demo-docker-cypress-included/blob/master/cy-run.sh
- https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-example-docker-compose

Note: I have tried a number of variations of baseUrl (localhost, my-app, etc). All resulting in the same problem.

Comment: Maybe 0.0.0.0:8080 will work?

Comment: The `CYPRESS_baseUrl` env variable is commented out in the compose file, is it required for Cypress to work?

Comment: @MarkoE I have tried very many variations of this as noted at the end of my post. If you have something specific you think I should try please specify.

Answer (score 9):

`localhost` in the context of a container is the container itself. So when your cypress container tries to connect to localhost:8080, it's trying to connect to port 8080 on itself.

Docker compose creates a virtual network where each container can be addressed by its service name. So cypress needs to connect to `http://my-app:8080/thank-you` rather than `http://localhost:8080/thank-you`.

The port it connects to when the connection is coming from a container on the same virtual network is the internal port. So it works even if you don't map the port. You only need to map the port if you want to access the container from the host.

Another thing to consider is that your node app needs to accept connections from other sources than localhost. If it doesn't, make sure you bind to 0.0.0.0 on your `app.listen`.

Comment: I noted at the bottom that I did attempt this. ie, changing links in my cypress tests from localhost:8080 to my-app:8080. These settings in conjunction with changing my first cy.visit were not successful. Could you provide more explicit instructions for your last sentence? (Bind to 0.0.0.0 on app.losten)

Comment: the `app.listen` bit was just my assumption that your vue app connects to an API written in nodejs. That wasen't very clearly put on my part. If you don't have a nodejs backend, my comment doesn't make any sense. Sorry about that.

Comment: Thank you Hans. This app has no back-end, just a vuex store. Appreciate the assistance here and the description of the docker compose virtual network. I also tried putting them in the same "network" by adding that to the docker-compose file. My understanding was that by having them on the same network they would "see" eachother with ports exposed, but it also didn't work.

Comment: I tried making a minimal example of 2 containers where one talks to the other here: https://gist.github.com/kodedylf/6812f761912b9ca0d0f2bfab77e57474. The client makes a request to http://webserver/ and the call goes to the other container.

Answer (score 2):

You can specify the composed service to use the host's network. With the key: `network_mode: host`. You will also want to specify baseUrl as localhost:8080. Here's a fully functional docker-compose file:

```
version: '3.5'
services:
    my-app:
        build: .
        ports: 
            - "8080:8080"
        volumes:
          - type: bind
            source: ./app
            target: /app
          - "/app/node_modules"
    cypress:
      image: "cypress/included:8.2.0"
      depends_on:
        - my-app
      #environment:
        - CYPRESS_baseUrl=http://localhost:8080 # and this
      working_dir: /app
      network_mode: host # this
      volumes: 
        - type: bind
          source: ./app
          target: /app

volumes: 
  app:
```